# Retrieving Spring Boot configuration from a database

Tags: java, spring, properties, configuration, spring-boot

Can anyone offer me some guidance on the best way for me to achieve this goal.

I'd like to extend the Spring Boot [Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) so that I have a single method which can be called from anywhere in my application. This method will retrieve a property value using a key. This method will first interrogate a database table and if it does not find the specified key it will then fall back on the PropertySource order described in [1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

So I'd have a service similar to:

```
@Service
public class ConfigurationService {

    private final ConfigurationRepository configurationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigurationService(ConfigurationRepository configurationRepository) {
        this.configurationRepository = configurationRepository;
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        Configuration configuration = configurationRepository.findOne(key);

        // Add something here to get the property from application.properties if the key does not exist in the db

        return configuration == null ? null : configuration.getValue();
    }

}
```

Which I can use as follows:

```
foo = configuration.getValue("my.property");
```

Is there a better way of going about this? Am I missing a Spring Boot feature that I could utilise?

I'd like to be able to change the values of the properties while the application is running and have these new values picked up.

Comment: Depending on how large your project/deployment is, this sounds like a potential case for Spring Cloud Config.

Comment: Write a `PropertySource` that is backed by the database, that way it just integrates with the rest of the system. Or simply write an `ApplicationInitializer` which loads all the properties from a database, wrap them in a `PropertiesPropertySource` and add them to the environment. At least you don't want to go calling this method around the whole place you want to integrate with the default mechanisms.

Comment: What about using cache in link with database for storing key-value pairs

Comment: I think a `PropertySource` backed by the database is what I require. How do I ensure that this is considered before application.properties etc.

Comment: By placing it on top of the other `PropertySources` or at the position you want it to be.

Comment: @m-deinum Are there any good examples I can take a look at?

Comment: @mip, can you post an answer on how you solved this issue?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza we never got around to implementing this. I think it would make a great addition to Spring Boot though.

Comment: @mip I have just implemented this, and actually posted a question about logging during this stage. Will post how I did it

Comment: @mip did this answer solve your question?

Answer (score 10):

I have used the EnvironmentPostProcessor spring feature to do this.

You need to create a class like this:

```
public class ReadDbPropertiesPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    /**
     * Name of the custom property source added by this post processor class
     */
    private static final String PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME = "databaseProperties";
    
    /**
     * Adds Spring Environment custom logic. This custom logic fetch properties from database and setting highest precedence
     */
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Map<String, Object> propertySource = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            // Build manually datasource to ServiceConfig
            DataSource ds = DataSourceBuilder
                    .create()
                    .username(USERNAME) // replace with your config
                    .password(PASSWORD) // replace with your config
                    .url(DATASOURCE-URL)// replace with your config
                    .driverClassName(DRIVER) // replace with your config
                    .build();

            // Fetch all properties
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = ds.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT name, value FROM propertyConfig WHERE service = ?");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, APP_NAME);
            
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            // Populate all properties into the property source
            while (rs.next()) {
                String propName = rs.getString("name");
                propertySource.put(propName, rs.getString("value"));
            }
            
            // Create a custom property source with the highest precedence and add it to Spring Environment 
            environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new MapPropertySource(PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME, propertySource));
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching properties from db");
        }
    }
}
```

Since you need to run this class at a very early stage of spring, you need to create the file `spring.factories` and register your environment post processor. This file needs to be located here:

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories
```

In the content you need to set your class to the spring property:

```
# Environment Post Processor
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=com.your.package.ReadDbPropertiesPostProcessor
```

Comment: what is PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME? I want add properties to default profile in my case: application.properties

Comment: @user3871754 it is the "key" name for the properties sources spring map `MapPropertySource`. Spring boot internally handles a map storing the property sources, and i'm adding a new with with `addFirst`

Comment: I had to use the following location for spring-factories. src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-factories