# Spring Cloud Config Server fallback mechanism with local database

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

I am able to work with cloud config server and it's working fine but I would like to know some more info. Let us assume a scenario -

1. Cloud config server is getting the values using git or some database.
2. My microservices are deployed on some different system which is not able to connect to config server due to network issue or something else. For the first time let us assume it got connected and getting the values. Now services are not able to connect to cloud config server but microservices are working as it didn't restart.
3. Now due to some reason, we would like to restart our microservices but config server it's not up. In that case, our application won't restart.

For keeping above scenario in mind, I would like to know do we have some extension or control on config server or config client so that when config server is getting down it should take the values from local DB so that my application will keep on running.
Later once the config server gets up, the Application will take the configuration from cloud config server only.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

When micro-service starts it tries to contact the cloud config service first. When cloud config server is not available, the microservice will "fallback" to other "sources" of configurations: application.properties/yaml, etc.

This it the default behavior out of the box.

Usually if you already have cloud config service, this means that you have pretty advanced setup. In this case, consider keeping a replica of cloud config servers for high availability + implement liveness probe to make sure they're up, so that if it goes down your infrastructure (kubernetes or whatever you have) will fire up another instance of the service.

You can also use cloud config service "embedded" into your application [see this tutorial](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__embedding_the_config_server.html)
But it looks like out of scope of this question

Comment: Hi Mark,
Thanks for the prompt response but we can't go with default configuration in the properties file. Also cloud config server is kept on running but due to network issue, my application is not able to connect to cloud config server.

Scenario is -

Comment: 1. I can't maintain the default values in application.properties because there is 100+ property. I would like to make a copy of the configuration server (last working one) i.e. sync between config server and local database so that each service can get the data from the database.

2. Liveness of Config server is not an issue and it's keep on running but my services are not able to reach/ connect to config server. 

In above case we would like to maintain the same copy of config server to our database.

Comment: I more meant that there are many fallbacks to the absence of config service. In general you can build your own ways of configurations. It can be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212633/spring-boot-retrieving-configuration-from-a-database or you can take a look on implementation of other  source of configuration (cloud config service itself, its opensource, or, say, https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul)

Comment: Thanks Mark,

I have checked config-client docs and found we can customize the application request while sending and providing our own implementation. Instead of looking to the config server, can we check the response of the app using config-client and if config server is not up, we ill get the data from local database and process further.